# Event is fired without any call to .next()

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-event-emitter, replaysubject

the problem i have is, every time the component `VisOpComponent` is initialized, the subscribed eventemitter gets fired without any call to `.next()`. i also added some console.log as shown below to show you that, despite the
`subEvtEmitterOnVisualizeBtnClicked` is not initialize but still the log statement in the event subscription can be called and it prints `subEvtEmitterOnVisualizeBtnClicked called`

please let me know why the event is getting fired without any invokation to `.next()` and how to fix it

**VisOpComponent**:

```
if(this.subEvtEmitterOnVisualizeBtnClicked) {
  if(this.subEvtEmitterOnVisualizeBtnClicked.closed){
    console.log("closed subEvtEmitterOnVisualizeBtnClicked")
  } else {
    console.log("NOT closed subEvtEmitterOnVisualizeBtnClicked")
  }
} else {
  console.log("subEvtEmitterOnVisualizeBtnClicked not initialized")
}

this.subEvtEmitterOnVisualizeBtnClicked = this._FromAwanti1ToVisOpService.getEmitterOnVisualizeButtonClicked().subscribe((param:number)=>{
  console.log("subEvtEmitterOnVisualizeBtnClicked called")
  this.visulizationOperationID = param
  this.submit()
})
```

**eventemitters**:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Component, OnInit, EventEmitter, Output } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject, Subject,ReplaySubject } from 'rxjs'

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class FromAwanti1ToVisOpOfAocAvghInterceptionService {
  
private emitterOnVisualizeButtonClicked:Subject<number> = new ReplaySubject<number>();
 
  constructor() { }
  
  public emitOnVisualizeButtonClicked(param) {
    this.emitterOnVisualizeButtonClicked.next(param)
  }
  public getEmitterOnVisualizeButtonClicked() {
    return this.emitterOnVisualizeButtonClicked.asObservable();
  }
```

**logs**:

```
vis-op.component.ts:45 constructor
vis-op.component.ts:59 subEvtEmitterOnVisualizeBtnClicked not initialized
vis-op.component.ts:63 subEvtEmitterOnVisualizeBtnClicked called
```

Comment: @Drenai i updated the code to some extent...i hope it is easier now to be followed

Comment: @Drenai would you please tell me what does number 1 mean in this context, why it is important

Comment: @Drenai i added log statement and it shows that .next did not get called

Answer (score 0):

If you are absolutely sure that `emitOnVisualizeButtonClicked(param)` never gets called to trigger that unwanted call on line 63 then you may want to check if you have more than one subscription happening - perhaps `VisOpComponent` got constructed before and there is no `unsubscribe()`?

Other reasoning would be the ReplaySubject itself. When a new subscription occurs, add it to the container and replay the values from the cache if any to the corresponding observer.

You could add an if guard

```js
this.subEvtEmitterOnVisualizeBtnClicked = this._FromAwanti1ToVisOpService.getEmitterOnVisualizeButtonClicked().subscribe((param:number)=>{
  if (!param) return;
  console.log("subEvtEmitterOnVisualizeBtnClicked called")
  this.visulizationOperationID = param
  this.submit()
})
```

Also important to know that ReplaySubject still replays the cached values before sending the complete or the error error notification to new subsequent subscriptions.

Add an buffer size of one `new ReplaySubject<number>(1)`. It can record and replay a whole series of values or one last value if we give `(1)`.

Comment: i added the if-guard and buffer size of 1 but still the same behavior occurs

Comment: So what does `param` contain?